# Destructuring Array in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way that I'm missing do this operation using destructuring an array.
My Array

```
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and I have a variable `rest`, `arr2` and `range=5`. And I want first `range` which is `5` elements from the array and rest of the elements in rest variable. The way I try it to be

`[arr2,...rest] = arr1`

In this case, `arr2` will have output `1` and `rest` have the rest of the array. Is there any way I can have first `5` elements in `arr2`

Comment: means, you just want to split the array?

Comment: You can `slice` it. But i don't think that it's possible with just destructuring.

Answer (score 2):

```
rest = arr1.slice()
arr2 = rest.splice(0, range)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not practical but just for fun you can do that (don't use it in real code though)

`const [arr2, rest] = [arr1.slice(0, range), arr1.slice(range)]`